# How to store a hash in Redis. I am using hset

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I want to store a Hash object in redis but it's not working.

```
const UpdateStatusOfEventofMap = (eventId , status)=>{
 console.log('in function eventId --->' , eventId , 'status == > ' , status)
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   try {
     // let data = JSON.stringify(GetResponderData);
     let updateEventStatus = client.hset('StatusOfEvent',eventId ,status,(err,reply)=>{
       if(err) console.log(err)
       resolve(reply)
     })
   } catch (e) {
       return reject(e)
   }
});
}
```

Comment: What is not working with the current code? what kind of error do you get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use hmset instead of hset. Try this code block.

```
const UpdateStatusOfEventofMap = (eventId , status)=>{
 console.log('in function eventId --->' , eventId , 'status == > ' , status)
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   try {
     // let data = JSON.stringify(GetResponderData);
     let updateEventStatus = client.hmset('StatusOfEvent',eventId ,status,(err,reply)=>{
       if(err) console.log(err)
       resolve(reply)
     })
   } catch (e) {
       return reject(e)
   }
});
}
```

Comment: Please notice HMSET is considered deprecate HSET should work too:
https://redis.io/commands/HMSET